# Overwriting a formula for a random value with the same formula. Value doesn't change?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that picks a random 'template' range of formulas from a sheet, puts it into a main sheet, then the formulas in the template get random values from other sheets. The problem I'm having is that `setFormulas()` sometimes 'changes' the formula of a cell to the same formula and it doesn't get a new random result. I'm currently trying to run `clearContent()` first, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
function generate(row)
{
  row = row * 3;

  var templates = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("templates");
  var generator = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("generator");

  var range = templates.getRange(1, 1, templates.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); //get a 2d array of the first column in the templates sheet (is there a way to get this as a 1d array?)
  var cells = [];
  for(i = 0; i < range.length; i++)
  {
    cells[i] = range[i][0]; // turn the 2d array into a 1d array
  }

  var end = cells.lastIndexOf(generator.getRange(2, 2).getValue()) + 3; // upper bound when getting a random template
  var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(end / 3)) * 3) + 1; // random row number
  var formulas = templates.getRange(rand, 1, 3, 6).getFormulas(); // get formulas from random template

  generator.getRange(row, 2, 3, 6).clearContent(); // it's all gone right?
  generator.getRange(row, 2, 3, 6).setFormulas(formulas); // so why is it still here?
}
```

I had it working properly, then I changed 'end' from being the last row of the template sheet to being based on a cell in the main sheet. I don't see how that could have any impact on the way `setFormulas()` behaves, though.

Comment: Can you explain/illustrate your objective more clearly?  I'm trying to dig in and understand this.  How are you invoking this function?  Are you using it as a user-defined function or something?  It's pretty rare that GAS functions take arguments except if they are user-defined.

Comment: I set row=3 and all it did was blow away B3:E5 in my sample sheet generators tab (which was only populated A1:E10)

Comment: Could you provide a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: Okay, I made a demo that generates random East-West College Bowl names. The middle names yes/no dropdown will generate middle names if "yes" is selected, and will generate either middle names or no middle names if "no" is selected. The problem is that only the middle name will update after the first generation, and only when it changes between having one and not having one. Click the dice button to generate a random result for that row. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RK4NR-RYrDzutjwB7i1uGakoCpmbJFmKdjjhvlDf8eg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why are you doing this by copying formulae if you're scripting anyway? Can you not just select a name, middle name and surname at random from the list and place them in the respective cells?

Comment: The non-demo version is more complicated. There are more fields and I have a few dozen templates that it pulls from to fill them in.

Comment: What is your variable `rand` meant to be represent? It *seems* to me that it represents whether it should get the formulae from row 1 or row 4 of the template sheet, but if this is the case why does it have a `Math.random()` call in it at all? It's always going to be 1 if `Has middle name` is `Yes` and 4 if it's `no`.